# Error running Worklight project as Visual Studio project

Tags: html, windows-8, visual-studio-2013, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an error when trying to run Worklight project as Visual Studio Project.

The project is set up in Eclipse Juno EE, Worklight version is 5.0.6.2. Project is successfully can be build and run as Android project. But when I run it from Eclipse menu Run->Run As->Visual Studio project I have an error:

Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegKeyEx(…) returned error code 5.

Failed Running Visual Studio: Cannot find Visual Studio 2012 or later.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks a lot in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Visual Studio 2012 or 2013?

In 5.0.6.x, if you have Visual Studio **2013** you will need to double-click the .csproj/.jsproj accordingly in order to open the project.

This is fixed in newer versions of Worklight; namely, Worklight 6.0.0.x and above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have VS 2013 and I do open solution in VS double_clicking the jsproj file. I just thought there is a way a way to run it from Eclipse.

Comment: There is, but not in Worklight 5.0.6.x; if your question is resolved, feel free to mark it as Answered.